# Grails get Session and Management in GSP view

Tags: grails, session-state

how to get session map object in View GSP ?
i want to not use action to send session in model .

i know that the class path of session is the following :

```
 org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsHttpSession
```

But how can i retrieve it in GSP view.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can access `HttpSession` directly using `session` variable in gsp, it is bound in view layer.

For example:

```
//gsp
<p>${session}</p>
<p>${session.properties}</p>
<p>${session.id}</p>
```